# How to show proper Gravatar in Careers

Tags: support, jobs

I currently have a picture of myself as my Stack Exchange Gravatar (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330204/ryan-berger)), yet on my [Stack Exchange CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ryandavidberger) it shows a generic Gravatar.

How do I change it to be my own custom picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either make sure that the e-mail you use for Careers is the same one as you use for Stack Overflow.

Or add the e-mail you use for Careers to Gravatar.

Comment: Also, it looks like emails are case-sensetive, so make sure you email is the same case as the one in your Gravater account.